# Scan for bluetooth devices Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

I am new to Bluetooth and this is the first time I am trying it, so I am trying to develop an application that scans for nearby Bluetooth devices and connects,
I am using **flutter_blue** package and I wrote this simple code to scan for devices, and there are two devices near it but when I run the app (real phone)  it does not discover them, I want to know what is wrong with my code,  I need help please.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

final FlutterBlue flutterBlue= FlutterBlue.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(title: Text("BLE"),),
   body: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
     stream:flutterBlue.state,
     builder: (context, snapshot){
       if(snapshot.data == BluetoothState.on)
         {
           return ScanForDevices(flutterBlue: flutterBlue,);
           //return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.data!.toString()}"),);
         }
        else if(snapshot.hasError ||snapshot.data == BluetoothState.unauthorized)
         {
           return Center(child: Text("Error"),);
         }
         else{
           return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
         },
       ),
     );
    } 
   }


 class _ScanForDevicesState extends State<ScanForDevices> {
   late List<ScanResult> result ;
  @override
   void initState() {
   // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    widget.flutterBlue.startScan();
    // scanning();
    }
   scanning() {

      widget.flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((event) {
      for(ScanResult r in event)
        {
          result.add(r);
          print(r.device.id.toString() + "\n");
        }
    });
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
     stream:FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
     builder: (context, snapshot){
       if(snapshot.hasData)
         {
           return ListView(
             // children: snapshot.data!.map((e)  {
            //   return  Text("${e.device.id.toString()}");
            // }).toList(),
              children: snapshot.data!.map((e) =>  ListTile(
              leading: IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.present_to_all_sharp),
                 onPressed: (){e.device.connect(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4),);},),
                  subtitle: Text("${e.device.name }\n ${e.device.id.id}"),
                  title: Text(e.device.id.toString()))).toList()
            // result.map((e) {
            //   return Text(e.device.id.toString());
            // }).toList(),
          );
        }
      if(snapshot.hasError)
        {
          return Text("Error");
        }
      else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      
    },
  ),
  );
 } 
 }
```

and it shows these log messages
[image]

Comment: flutter_blue allows you to interact with Bluetooth Low Energy devices. These devices need to actively advertise their presence to be detected. When you say there are 2 devices around you, what kind of devices are they? Please use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to see if there are actually BLE devices advertising around you.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I have my laptop and another mobile phone next to my mobile which the flutter app installed in, I am new to BLE, please can you help to solve this problem, when I open BLE for the other phone it appears the BLE devices around it, but when I use flutter app it does not, please how can I communicate and scan using flutter app

Comment: I have no idea what Low Energy devices means and how to communicate, I am new to BLE @MichaelKotzjan

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy is a standard of Bluetooth that is incompatible with the "old" Bluetooth Classic (or Serial). It works different and requires a device to advertise its presence and the services it offers. If your Laptop and phone do not advertise they can't be found. Please start reading more information about BLE if you want to use it. This comment does not offer enough space to go through everything. The [Github page](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue) does also offer a lot of information regarding the usage of flutter_blue